# Split with Regex not returning properly with numbers

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string in two using a regex. The input string is in the format `"Something something something 30min"` for example. It always ends with a time in minutes in this format. I need to split it into `"Something something something"` and `"30min"`. My solution right now is:

```
String[] separatedLine = line.split("(?=(\\d)+)" );
```

But then I get "Something something something" and 3. If I try instead:

```
String[] separatedLine = line.split("(?=(\\d\\d))" );
```

It works, but I do not know the size of my number, it can be 5 or it can be 180 for all I know. I tried many different combinations but none seem to do the trick for every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex using **word boundary**:

```
String[] separatedLine = line.split("(?=\\b\\d)" );
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY4bL4/1)

This will split just before `30` but not between `3` and `0`.

Comment: Thsi solution worked, thank you very much. But so I understand, ?=\\b\\d means that I will look for a "word" beginning with a digit?

Comment: Right it will work if there number is at start OR else if there is any non-word character before the number.

Answer (score 0):

Just split according to the space which exists before the number.

```
String[] separatedLine = line.split("\\s+(?=\\d+)" );
```

OR

Add `min` after the number if necessary.

```
String[] separatedLine = line.split("\\s+(?=\\d+min)" );
```

**code:**

```
String s = "Something something something 30min";
String[] parts = s.split("\\s+(?=\\d+)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[Something something something, 30min]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
String[] split = "Something something something 30min".split("(?<!\\d)(?=\\d+)");
```

It will split your `String` whenever a number appears that is not preceded by another number.